# Forward declaration vs include in Google c++ style guide

Tags: c++, include, forward-declaration

Google c++ style has the following. I don't understand why forward declaration will call f(void*).

It can be difficult to determine whether a forward declaration or a full #include is needed. Replacing an #include with a forward declaration can silently change the meaning of code:

```
  // b.h:
  struct B {};
  struct D : B {};

  // good_user.cc:
  #include "b.h"
  void f(B*);
  void f(void*);
  void test(D* x) { f(x); }  // calls f(B*)
```

If the #include was replaced with forward decls for B and D, test() would call f(void*).

Comment: If you just do `struct D;` then the inheritance is not known.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the two cases individually. By replacing the `#include` with the header's content, we first have :

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};

void f(B*) {}
void f(void*) {}
void test(D* x) { f(x); }
```

There are two possible overloads. Since `D` inherits from `B` then `D*` is implicitly convertible to `B*`. Out of `B*` and `void*` the first is a better match so that overload is chosen. But in the case of a forward declared `B` and `D` :

```
struct B;
struct D;

void f(B*) {}
void f(void*) {}
void test(D* x) { f(x); }
```

`D` is not known to inherit from `B` so there is no implicit conversion possible from `D*` to `B*`. The only matching overload is `f(void*)`.